# Why I cannot use Arrays class in my Java project?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to compile [this](http://www.jensign.com/JavaScience/javacrypto/BCVerifyISig.txt) program in my IntelliJ IDE, but my IDE returns that *it cannot resolve Arrays symbol*.

*Click to enlarge*

[image]

Note that as you see in the left sidebar,I already added all the required libraries to my project!

This is imports of my program :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.*;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
```

As you see I added `import java.util.Arrays` to the program imports also, but nothing changed and I still have the above problem with `Arrays`.

Note that I tried to run the program on another computer, with the same version of IntelliJ IDE, but `JDK 1.7` installed, and I have this problem there, but In my current computer (That JDK 1.8 is installed), the above problem appears.

---

**Update:**

In the line `import java.util.Arrays`, `Arrays` is red and that means there is no `Arrays` class in `util`. Why I should have this error, while I install JDK 1.8 and added all of its libraries to my project?

Comment: Do you have an `import java.util.Arrays;` statement in your source file?

Comment: @Eran I tried that also, but nothing changed!

Comment: `Array` and `Arrays` are 2 different classes from `java.lang.reflect.Array` and `java.util.Arrays`. Please change your question.

Comment: @Codebender Thanks for your cooment. Question edited.

Comment: Post a complete minimal class reproducting the problem. As code, not as an image. We still can't see your imports.

Comment: I simply copy-pasted your code into my IDE (eclipse). No problem with class `Arrays` as you have the correct import statement. Additionally, I cannot see any error in your screenshot regarding that class. Where do I fail?

Comment: @JBNizet The link of program is in the first line of my question. all is the same.I added `import java.lang.Arrays` to it also.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I tried that solution also! I mean I tried it on another computer with **JDK 1.7** and IntelliJ and it seems ok, but there is the above problem with my current computer! (JDK 1.8 intalled)

Comment: Down-voters, please explain why?

Comment: I downvoted because of you didn't provide your imports section, not example program. Also, not sure for Idea, but Eclipse allows to add missed imports with quick fix feature

Comment: @Abraham What solution did you try also? I did not provide a solution! I told you that there is no error in your code. Additionally, there is no error in your screenshot. Regarding the downvotes: You were already told (by JB Nizet) to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with code in your question (not as a link). And your explanations do not correspond to your code and screenshot. This question is very unclear.

Comment: @SergeyMaksimenko The example is the program that I used! I simply copy&paste the contents of that sample program to my IDE. anyway I will add its import part to my program.

Comment: @Abraham No, it's not. You still did not do, what you are asked to do. I'm out.

Comment: Do you have another working Java projects (jdk8) on this computer? Does IDEA compiles them? Did you try to reload IDE?This is not the brightest idea, but it helps in some cases

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Sorry, the problem that I have is that my IDE don't recognize `Arrays` as an defined/imported class! Can we call it error? In IntelliJ IDE, the classes/methods/variables that are not defined are in red.

Comment: Do you have any other Java projects that compile and work on this computer? Try making a small project that only does something with java.util.Arrays and see if that compiles. If I remember right, you can hover over errors with IntelliJ and it will give you a possible response or fix.

Comment: @SergeyMaksimenko Yes I have. I successfully compile and run (this)[http://www.jensign.com/JavaScience/javacrypto/BCSignFile.txt] program for example.

Comment: @Scooter When I try to import `java.util.Arrays`, the `Arrays` turn to red. That mean the `Arrays` is not in `util` package! why? I simply installed JDK 1.8 and add it to my project as you see above

Comment: Try making sure all your other errors are fixed first - for example, I notice that this code is in a file called verify.java. when it should be in a file called BCVerifyISig.java.